# Form submission asks to save exe, would like it to run instead

Tags: html, forms, cgi

When I submit my basic form from the html file, it gives me the option to save the exe
I just want the exe to run instead. (To re-populate the template html file)
What do I need to do to just run the exe once the form is submitted?

```
<form action="Lib.exe" method=POST ID="Form1">
Enter Index to DELETE<br>
<input type=text name="user" ID="Text1">
<input type=submit value="DELETE">
</form>
```

I am running a web server. The html file and the .exe are in the directory to run web files.

Any help is appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Figured it out. I didn't have the content type in the CGI app.
" Content-type: text/html"
Without this the web server won't execute it. Newbie error. Thanks guys.

Now my html file runs on the web server, the form calls the exe in the cgi-bin directory and executes the deletion, specified by the user.

My next challenge is figuring out how to not actually display or go to the Lib.exe in the browser. I want it to run as it's doing, but stay at my html page as it is now updated. i don't want to have to manually go back to my html page.

Answer (score 1):

I assume the lib.exe does its template updating on the server, meaning you need to configure your web server to run exe files instead of serving them to the user. You do not specify the server you run (somehow I assume you run IIS...), but in Apache you would use `<FilesMatch>` in `httpd.conf` to add a handler for exe, something like this:

```
<FilesMatch \.cgi$>
    SetHandler cgi-script
</FilesMatch>
```

but adapted to exes. See [mod_mime documentation](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_mime.html) here.

Answer (score 1):

1. Please clarify your question. What are the OS and the web-server, does web server run with restricted permissions?
2. Can you port Lib.exe into the language used by your web-site (PHP or ASP or whatever)?
3. Executing server side scripts as CGI for small tasks can slow down the system as the OS needs to start a new process, allocate resources for the new process, etc... Compiled C++ can be slower than PHP interpreted by loaded module.

Answer (score 1):

You can use AJAX instead of form submitting and achieve the same result.